# Prove that $e^{-A} = (e^{A})^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

Let $A, B \in R^{n \times n}$. Prove that $e^{-A} = (e^{A})^{-1}$.

($R$ is the real numbers)

I've tried messing around with both sides, evaluated as sums. I just can't get the two to match up.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: I've edited the question to exactly what I have been asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another less elegant way:

$$e^A = I+ A + \frac{A^2}{2!}+ \frac{A^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
$$e^{-A} = I - A + \frac{A^2}{2!}-\frac{A^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

$$e^A \, e^{-A} = I + \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k A^k$$

where $$b_k =\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^j}{j! (k-j)!}= \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j {k \choose j}=\frac{1}{k!}(1-1)^k =0$$

Answer (score 10):

You should know that if $X,Y\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and $XY=YX$, then $e^{X+Y}=e^Xe^Y$.

With this in mind, simply compute $e^Ae^{-A}$.

Comment: @ Git Gud:  It would not surprise me if you intended to type $X, Y  \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ rather than $X, Y \in \Bbb R^n$ here.  Should I be surprised?

Comment: @RobertLewis In fact you shouldn't. Thanks!

Comment: right on! Glad to help out!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you allow that $e^{a + b} = e^a e^b$ and $e^0 = 1$, which are general properties of exponential functions and don't even really require anything special about $e$, in the sense that they're true for *any* base, then you don't need power series and you can simply note that

$e^x e^{-x} = e^{(x + (-x))} =  e^0 = 1, \tag{1}$

which immediately yields, upon multiplication by $(e^x)^{-1}$,

$(e^x)^{-1} = e^{-x}. \tag{2}$

If you don't yet have $e^{a + b} = e^a e^b$, I would try using the series $e^x =\sum_i (x^i / i!)$ to show it is true; it's an easier path, I suspect.

A proof of $e^{a + b} = e^a e^b$ is given in *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an,Introduction to Chaos*, by Hirsch, Smale, and Devaney, chapter 6.  They do it for commuting matrices, but the series estimates are basically the same.

***Note added in edit, Thursday 5 December 2013 3:14 PM PST:*** My answer was entered *before* the question was altered to address matrices, and I'm *not* going to re-type it *now*; but if anyone wants to see something which resolves the matrix case as well, check out my answer to [$M,N\in \Bbb R ^{n\times n}$, show that $e^{(M+N)} = e^{M}e^N$ given $MN=NM$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568450/m-n-in-bbb-r-n-times-n-show-that-emn-emen-given-mn-nm)
***End of note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***