# Procedure for 3 by 3 Non homogenous Linear systems (Differential Equations)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the problem I have. $$x^{'}(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 5&-3&-2\\8&-5&-4\\-4&3&3 \end{pmatrix} f(t)=\begin{pmatrix} -\sin (t)\\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

I am trying to find the general solution to this problem. I found the eigenvalue to be 1 (it is repeated). Afterwards I solved the system $4x_1-3x_2-2x_1=0$ for $x_1$ and chose values so that I would not have decimals to be the following:

$$e_1= \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I am kind of stuck at this point on what to do. Do I need to solve $$\begin{pmatrix}4&-3&-2\\8&-6&-4\\-4&3&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ but than where do I go from there?

Comment: You forgot an $=$ in your equation.

Comment: Your differential equation is
$$x^{'}(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)\quad?$$

Comment: @adam Do you know how to compute matrix exponentials? You should be getting two linearly indepdent eigenvectors.

Comment: Ahhh yes I'm missing a =. Where is the 2nd one

Comment: @adam Finding the second eigenvector won't solve all of your problems. If you show us your computations, someone will tell you what you did wrong, but you'll still be a long way from finding the solution after having two linearly independent eigenvectors. Do you know how to compute $e^{At}$?

Comment: Yes it is just the diagonlized matrix of the exp ( eigenvalues )

Comment: But the thing is I have less eigenvalues than I do to write this matrix

Comment: @adam The problem is not the lack of eigenvalues, but a lack of eigenvectors. You'd like to get three linearly independent eigenvectors so you could diagonalize the matrix. But you can't because the matrix isn't diagonalizable. Do you know about jordan normal form?

Comment: not exactly thats probably what is giving me problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & -3 & -2 \\ 8 & -5 & -4 \\ -4 & 3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}, ~~ F[t] = \begin{bmatrix} - \sin t \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

We can find the solution to this system using:

$$X(t) = e^{At}X_0 + \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-s)}F(s)~ds$$

If we find the Jordan Normal Form of the matrix, we have:

$$A = PJP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & -4 & 0 \\ -\dfrac{3}{2} & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 \\ -\dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & \dfrac{3}{2} & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

**Update** How did we find these eigenvectors?

$A$ has only two Jordan blocks for only one eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, so:

$$A-I \ne 0 \\ (A-I)^2  = 0$$

Thus, we can take **any** vector $v_3$ such that $(A-I)v_3 \ne 0$, which becomes an eigenvector of rank $2$. So, take:

$$v_3 = (0,0,1) \implies (A-I)v_3 \ne 0$$

Now, we have:

$$v_2 = (A-I)v_3 = (-2,-4,2)$$

Lastly, we need a third linearly independent eigenvector such that:

$$(A-I)v_1 = 0 \implies v_1 = \left(0,1,-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)$$

Note: $P$ is made up of three generalized eigenvectors, $P = [v_1~|~v_2~|~v_3]$, from the single eigenvalue, since we need three linearly independent eigenvectors.

We can now find $e^{Jt}$ as:

$$E^{Jt} =e^t\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & t \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

We can now write the fundamental matrix as:

$\phi(t) = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & -4 & 0 \\ -\dfrac{3}{2} & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} e^t\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & t \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 \\ -\dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & \dfrac{3}{2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

So,

$$ \phi(t) = e^t\begin{bmatrix} 4t+1 & -3t & -2t \\ 8t & 1-6t & -4t \\ -4t & 3t & 2t+1 \end{bmatrix}$$

We now have:

$$\phi^{-1}(t) = e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix} 1-4t & 3t & 2t \\ -8t & 6t+1 & 4t \\ 4t & -3t & 1-2t\end{bmatrix}$$

- Find $\phi^{-1}(t) \cdot F(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
   e^{-t} (4 t+(4 t-1) \sin (t)) \\
   8 e^{-t} t (\sin (t)+1) \\
   e^{-t} (-4 \sin (t) t-4 t+2) \\
  \end{bmatrix}$
- Now we integrate the previous result, that is $w = \int \phi^{-1}(t) F(t)$ and this gives us: $w$
- Next, we find:

$X(t) = X_h + X_p = \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \\z(t) \end{bmatrix} = e^{At}X_0 + \phi(t) w = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 e^t (4 t+1)-3 c_2 e^t t-2 c_3 e^t t-4 t (2 t+t \sin (t)+(t+1) \cos (t)+1)+12 t (2 t+t \sin (t)+(t+1) \cos (t)+2)-\frac{1}{2} (4 t+1) (8 (t+1)+(4 t-1) \sin (t)+(4 t+3) \cos (t)) ~~~\\ ~~~8 c_1 e^t t-c_2 e^t (6 t-1)-4 c_3 e^t t-8 t (2 t+t \sin (t)+(t+1) \cos (t)+1)+4 (6 t-1) (2 t+t \sin (t)+(t+1) \cos (t)+2)-4 t (8 (t+1)+(4 t-1) \sin (t)+(4 t+3) \cos (t)) ~~~ \\ ~~~-4 c_1 e^t t+3 c_2 e^t t+c_3 e^t (2 t+1)+2 (2 t+1) (2 t+t \sin (t)+(t+1) \cos (t)+1)-12 t (2 t+t \sin (t)+(t+1) \cos (t)+2)+2 t (8 (t+1)+(4 t-1) \sin (t)+(4 t+3) \cos (t)) \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: where exactly did you get the $P$ matrix from?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which eigenvectors you refer too since there are only 2 yet you have 3

Comment: No I am not exactly.

Comment: I am still trying to understand the procedure

Comment: I'm not familiar with the linear algebra portion of this course because I've never taken it. But I am still having difficulty understanding what is happening. By the way there was a 2 on F(T) 3rd row of the matrix instead of a 0. That could be throwing me off

Comment: Ok so I understand how you got the 1st 2  eigenvector columns. That 3rd one I cannot find a linear combination based on $4x_1=3x_2+2x_3$

Comment: Everything that could go wrong went wrong in this problem...

Comment: after doing some reading on the jordan form I have some sort of understanding but what is confusing me is knowing what your systems of equations are going to be for the 3rd eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks these notes are much easier to understand than the textbook I have which can't seem to focus on one subject and jumps around

Comment: The book is called Elementary differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by Boyce. The problem was given to us by a professor who got the problem from the textbook and decided to make it more complicated because it was too easy

Comment: you think you can help me out with this other problem I encountered?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765206/finding-a-particular-solution-to-the-non-homogenous-system?noredirect=1#comment1590287_765206

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know about jordan normal form, since $A$ can't be diagonalized and since $A$ as only one eigenvalue, there's one little trick you can use.

For all $t\in \mathbb R$ it holds that $e^{At}=e^te^{(A-I)t}=e^{t}\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac 1{n!}(A-I)^nt^n\right)$. Now note that $(A-I)^2$ is the null matrix.

Proceed with your favourite method. ([This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744296/differential-equations-diagonalizable-matrix/744324#744324) might help).