# Non-homogenous System where did I go wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the system $\vec{x^{'}}=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -5\\1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+ \begin{pmatrix} -\cos t\\ \sin t \end{pmatrix}$

The Eigenvalues are $(2-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)+5=0 \implies \lambda=\pm i$

The Eigevalue we choose is $\lambda=i$ and get a fundamental matrix of $$ \phi(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 5\cos t & 5\sin t\\ 2\cos t + \sin t & 2\sin t - \cos t \end{pmatrix}$$
We find the inverse by \begin{gather*}
\phi^{-1}(t)=\dfrac{1}{5\cos t(2\sin t-\cos t)- 5\sin t(2 \cos t+ \sin t)} \begin{pmatrix} 2\sin t - \cos t & -5\sin t\\ -2 \cos t - \sin t & -5\cos t \end{pmatrix}=\\[8pt]\dfrac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} \cos t-2\sin t & 5\sin t\\ 2 \cos t + \sin t & 5\cos t \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

We multiply by $g(t)$ and have \begin{gather*}\dfrac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} \cos t-2\sin t & 5\sin t\\ 2 \cos t + \sin t & 5\cos t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -\cos t\\ \sin t \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\cos^2 t+2\sin t\cos t +5 \sin^2 t\\ -2\cos^2 t -2\cos t \sin t +5\cos t \sin t \end{pmatrix}=\\[8pt]\begin{pmatrix} 5 \sin^2 t-\cos^2 t +2 \sin t \cos t\\ -2\cos^2 t +3\sin t \cos t \end{pmatrix}\end{gather*}

Integrating all of this yields $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{2}t - \frac{5}{4}\sin 2t - \frac{1}{2}t -\frac{1}{4}\sin 2t + \sin^2 t\\[8pt] -t-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2 t\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2t-3\sin 2t +\sin^2 t\\ -t-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2 t \end{pmatrix}$$

Multiply by $\phi(t)$ and we have \begin{gather*}\begin{pmatrix} 5\cos t & 5\sin t\\ 2\cos t + \sin t & 2\sin t - \cos t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2t-3\sin 2t +\sin^2 t\\ -t-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2 t \end{pmatrix}=\end{gather*}
$$\begin{pmatrix} 10t\cos t -15 \sin 2t \cos t +5 \sin^2 t \cos t-5t\sin t -\frac{5}{2}\sin 2t \sin t+\frac{15}{2}\sin^3 t \\ 4t \cos t +2t \sin t -6 \sin 2t \cos t -3 \sin t \sin 2t+2\cos t \sin^2 t + \sin^3 t -2t\sin t  +2t\cos t -\sin 2t \sin t+\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t \cos t +3\sin^3 t-\frac{3}{2}\sin^2 t \cos t \end{pmatrix}     
\dfrac{1}{5}$$

The book gets $x_h+\begin{pmatrix}2\\1 \end{pmatrix} t \cos t -\begin{pmatrix}1\\
0 \end{pmatrix} t \sin t$

So how did they simplify all that?

Comment: I just realized I forgot to multiply by the integral of the bottom row of the matrix. However it doesn't change the fact that it is still complicated as hell. They got $c_1\begin{pmatrix} 5\cos t\\2\cos t+\sin t \end{pmatrix} +c_2\begin{pmatrix} 5\sin t \\ -\cos t +2 \sin t \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So I reworked it with the missing factor... it makes it look worse actually heh

Comment: dont tell me I messed up at the beggining

Comment: does it have to do with me taking the inverse and missing a sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the author used $\lambda = i$ and $v_1 = (5, 2-i)$ for the calculations.

You have a sign issue:

$$\phi^{-1}(t)=\dfrac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} \cos t-2\sin t & 5\sin t\\ 2 \cos t + \sin t & -5\cos t \end{pmatrix}$$

Look at the sign of entry $\phi^{-1}(t)_{22}$, which should be a negative.

Multiplying by $g(t)$, we get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \sin ^2(t)-\frac{1}{5} \cos (t) (\cos (t)-2 \sin (t)) \\
 -\cos (t) \sin (t)-\frac{1}{5} \cos (t) (2 \cos (t)+\sin (t)) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Integrating, we get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{2 t}{5}-\frac{1}{10} \cos (2 t)-\frac{3}{10} \sin (2 t) \\
 \frac{3 \cos ^2(t)}{5}-\frac{1}{10} \sin (2 t)-\frac{t}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Expanding the trig terms, we get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{10} \cos ^2(t)-\frac{3}{5} \sin (t) \cos (t)+\frac{\sin ^2(t)}{10}+\frac{2 t}{5} \\
 \frac{3 \cos ^2(t)}{10}-\frac{1}{5} \sin (t) \cos (t)-\frac{t}{5}-\frac{3 \sin ^2(t)}{10}+\frac{3}{10} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Multiplying by $\phi(t)$, we get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(2 t-\frac{1}{2}\right) \cos (t)-t \sin (t) \\
 \frac{1}{10} (2 (5 t-4) \cos (t)+\sin (t)) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Of course the $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ terms get absorbed into the constants and you are left with the author's result.

Comment: WOW! really like man all that work...

Comment: I am also covering trajectories with non-linear system and autonomous systems. The only think I'm having issues with is how to connect each trajectory to the different critical points. Do you know any way to check to see if your trajectory is right by having something graph it?

Comment: No for non-linear autonomous systems. Also I am still getting a complicated answer despite the sign change it doesn't look like its changing much

Comment: how are you going to draw a phase portrait in latex?

Comment: when you integrated what idenity did you use??? because I had double angles everywhere

Comment: sorry but where do you get the lone term $\dfrac{3}{10}$ from?

Comment: ok so the only terms that matter when we multiply this matrix is the $t$ term right because for the top row im getting $\frac{2t}{5}\cos t-\frac{t}{5}\sin t$

Comment: I get the answer if I just ignore the $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ that appear by themselves. I haven't the slightest clue how you simplified all that to actually get the constants, since trig identities can go many different directions.

Comment: the book introduces 4 different methods to solve these and fails to explain each one clearly

Comment: Yes I'll post one of the problems right now. I have the method down for that one just the trajectories are kind of not all there. Also what program are you going to use to draw the trajectories and post them as a graphics or do you plan to draw by hand?

Comment: I posted the problem