# How to solve this system of inhomogeneous differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

In some past exam papers for the Maths course that I attend,I found this example and I would really appreciate if someone looked at my solution. It goes like this: Find general solution to 
$$
y_1' = 2 y_1 - y_2 + (x+1) e^{3x}, \\
y_2' = y_1 + 4 y_2 + 2 x e^{3x}.
$$

First of all, I set up the fundamental matrix and found its eigenvalues. I got that the matrix has repeated roots namely $r=3$. As I could not find two linearly independent eigenvectors (I had just one), I used this method I had found online to obtain another eigenvector given just one (not convinced that the method is $100 \%$ legitimate though). My eigenvectors are thus $v_1 = (1,-1)$ and $v_2 = (0,-1)$. Therefore my homogeneous solution matrix is 
$$
y  = c_1 e^{3x} v_1 + c_2 (x e^{3x} v_1 + e^{3x} v_2).
$$

Then, I searched for the inverse of this matrix and got
$$
\left(
\array{(1+x) e^{-3x} &x e^{-3x} \\
-e^{-3x} &-e^{-3x}}
\right)
$$
Multiplying this matrix with the inhomogeneous matrix $( (x+1) e^{3x} , 2 x e^{3x})$ I obtained $(3 x^2x+1, -3x-1)$, which upon integrating, I got $(x^3 +x^2+x, -\frac{3}{2} x-x)$. Adding this matrix and the homogeneous matrix, I obtained the general solution.

Is this correct?

Comment: What you call the 'other eigenvector' is a [generalized eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector). I don't feel like reading your answer, but for some examples on this kind of problem see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744296/differential-equations-diagonalizable-matrix/744324#744324), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776402/system-of-nonhomogeneous-des-help-solving/776444#776444) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748496/procedure-for-3-by-3-non-homogenous-linear-systems-differential-equations).

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset formulas. As it's currently written, your question is far from being easy to understand.