# How to physically interpret solutions to linear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

Consider the differential equation
$$
y' = a(t)y + b(t).
$$
The general solutions takes the form $y : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$
(1) \qquad y(t) = w(t, 0)c_0 + \int_{0}^t w(t,s) b(s) ds,
$$
where $w(t,s) = e^{\int_s^t a(\tau) d\tau}$ is such that $y(t) = w(t,s)c_s$ is a solution to $y' = a(t)y$ given $y(s) = c_s$.

**Question.** How can we physically interpret the solutions $(1)$ in terms of $w$ and $b$? How can this solution be guessed from simple principles?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744296/differential-equations-diagonalizable-matrix/744324#744324).

Comment: Thanks for the links. They describe a standard method of finding the solutions. For the passerby, I'll just point out that they are precisely *not* the type of answers I'm looking for, as they are not easily interpretable.

Comment: @ Olivier : How do you physically interpret $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ ?

Comment: That is up to you. In my answer below, I give one interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

**Linearity principle:** If $b(t) = b_1(t)  + b_2(t)$, then the solutions $y_i$ to $y' = a(t)y + b_i(t)$ are such that $y = y_1 + y_2$ is a solution to $y' = a(t)y + b(t)$.

Let $y$ be the amount of money in a bank account (or $n$ bank account) with a continuously variable interest rate that is, at each time $t$, a linear function of $y$. Furthermore, money is added and withdrawn from the account following $b(t)$: in any time interval $I$,  $\int_I b(t) dt$ is the amount added during the time interval $I$. Thus $y$ satisfies the differential equation $y' = a(t) y + b(t)$. At time $t=0$, we suppose $y(t) = 0$ (money is only added through $b$).

We can simplify the situation by modelling the money input as discrete chunks. Thus, in the interval $[0,t]$, we write
$$
b(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(t), \quad b_i(t) = b(t) \chi_{R_i}(t),
$$
where $R_i = \left[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}\right]$. The solutions $y_i$ to $y' = a(t) y + b_i$ are approximately the solutions to $y' = a(t)y$ given $y\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n}b\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$. Thus
$$
y_i(t) \approx \frac{1}{n}w\left(t, \frac{i}{n}\right) b\left(\frac{i}{n}\right).
$$
By the "linearity principle", the solution to $y' = a(t)y + b(t)$ is then 
$$
y(t) \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n w\left(t, \frac{i}{n}\right)b\left(\frac{i}{n}\right).
$$
Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ we can guess that
$$
y(t) = \int_{0}^tw(t,s) b(s) ds.
$$