# Deducing the exact solution of a ODE

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

In page 53 of Arieh Iserles's *A first course in the numerical analysis of differential equations*, he presents the following ODE:

$(\vec{y})'=\Gamma\cdot\vec{y}$,

$\vec{y}(0)=\vec{y_0}$

Using the fact that the spectral factorization of $\Gamma$ gives us $\Gamma=VDV^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues and $V$ is the corresponding eigenvector matrix, he deduces (without working) that the exact solution of the ODE is: $\vec{y}(t)=e^{t\Gamma} = Ve^{tD}V^{-1}\vec{y_0}$

1. In order to get $\vec{y}(t)=e^{t\Gamma}$ it looks like he did: $\displaystyle \int \frac{(\vec{y})'}{\vec{y}} dt = \int \Gamma dt$. But how can he do this when $\vec{y}$ is a vector?
2. Using the spectral factorization, $e^{t\Gamma} = e^{tVDV^{-1}}$. How did he get $Ve^{tD}V^{-1}\vec{y_0}$ from this?

Comment: You have several answers now. Any comments or questions on any of them?

Comment: Yeah, apologies for the late reply, was very preoccupied with work today. I've just asked a question regarding one of them. Don't worry about me leaving the question open; I always accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question I present below was copied from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744324/55235) answer of mine and it works whether the matrix is diagonalizable or not.

Given $n\in \mathbb N, A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, a non trivial interval $I, t_0\in I, y_0\in \mathbb R^n$ and $b\colon I\to \mathbb R^n$ a continuous function, consider the initial value problem
$$y'+Ay=b, y(t_0)=y_0.$$

Let $f\colon I\to\mathbb R^n$ be a differentiable function.

**Fact:** [For all $t\in \mathbb R$, $e^{At}$ is invertible and $\left(e^{At}\right)^{-1}=e^{-At}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594722/prove-that-e-a-ea-1?lq=1).

There exists $C\in \mathbb R^n$ such that for all $t\in I$ the following holds:
$$\begin{align}
f'(t)+Af(t)=b(t)&\iff e^{At}(f'(t)+Af(t))=e^{At}b(t)\\
&\iff e^{At}f'(t)+e^{At}Af(t)=e^{At}b(t)\\
&\iff e^{At}f'(t)+Ae^{At}f(t)=e^{At}b(t)\\
&\iff \int \limits _{t_0}^te^{As}f'(s)+Ae^{As}f(s)\mathrm ds=\int \limits_{t_0}^te^{As}b(s)\mathrm ds+C\\
&\iff e^{At}f(t)=\int \limits_{t_0}^te^{As}b(s)\mathrm ds+C\\
&\iff f(t)=e^{-At}\int \limits_{t_0}^te^{As}b(s)\mathrm ds+e^{-At}C.
\end{align}$$

Taking into account $f(t_0)=y_0$ after some simple calculations it follows that $C=e^{At_0}y_0$.

---

As for the second question, just use the definition of matrix exponential together with what was done above:
$$\begin{align} e^{t\Gamma }&=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac {t^n} {n!}\Gamma^n\right)\\ &=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac {t^n} {n!}\left(VDV^{-1}\right)^n\right) \\
&=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac {t^n} {n!}VD^nV^{-1}\right)\\
&=V\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac {t^n} {n!}D^n\right)V^{-1}\\
&=Ve^{tD}V^{-1}. \end{align}$$

Comment: Hi! Sorry if this is a silly question, but how did you manage to shift the A in $e^{At}A$ to $Ae^{At}$?

Comment: @TwilightSparkle $$\forall t\in \mathbb R\left[e^{At}A=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac 1{n!}A^n\right)A=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac 1{n!}A^{n+1}\right)=A\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac 1{n!}A^n\right)\right].$$

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are confused by the formal procedure... don't write $\int \frac{(\vec{y})'}{\vec{y}}dt=\int \Gamma dt$, it doesn't make a lot of sense in this form unless you really specify what you mean by any of the operations here.

It's much simpler than that. You can imagine substituting $\vec{w}=V^{-1}\vec{v}$. Now, your set of differential equations reads as

$$(\vec{w})'=D\vec{w}$$

Because $D$ is diagonal, the components are not coupled and the above is a set of $n$ independent differential equation, which can each be integrated separately.

Additionally, it's perfectly fine to solve by Ansatz without integration, in which case you don't get have ambiguous expression.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=Vu$. Then $y'=Vu'$, but also $y'=\Gamma y=\Gamma Vu$, so $Vu'=\Gamma Vu$, so $u'=V^{-1}\Gamma Vu=Du$. Since $D$ is diagonal we can solve this: $u=e^{tD}u_0$. That's $y=Vu=Ve^{tD}u_0=Ve^{tD}V^{-1}y_0$.