# What does $e^{Ax}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$y'=Ay+b$$ , where $A$ is a $n\times n$-matrix,
 y and b are vectors of functions $(y_1(x),...y_n(x))^T$ and $(b_1(x),...,b_n(x))^T$

Suppose, we have found the general solution of the homogenous equation $$y'=Ay$$

The standard approach is to continue with the "variation of the constants". But in 
 a script, I found that the matrix $e^{Ax}$ has something to do with the special solution
 of the inhomogenous equation.

What is the meaning of $e^{Ax}$ ?

For example, let $$A=\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&2}$$ , $$b=\pmatrix{-e^{3x}\\e^{3x}}$$

What is $e^{Ax}$ and a special solution of $$y'=Ay+b$$ ?

Comment: Don't you mean $e^Ax$?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that the script means $e^{Ax}$ and not $e^Ax=exp(A)x$

Comment: I assumed that for each entry $a_{ij}$, we get $\large e^{a_{ij}x}$, but this does not work.

Comment: Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential? @Peter, also see: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/NonhomoSys.pdf

Comment: I cannot see any link between $exp(Ax)$ and a solution of the differential equation, so probably this is not meant.

Comment: @Peter The link is completely explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772544/deducing-the-exact-solution-of-a-ode/772651#772651).

Comment: @Peter, $y = e^{Ax}b$ is the unique solution of $\frac{dy}{dx} = Ay, y(0) = b.$

Comment: Actually, on a second reading of your question, I think my answer answers you completely. I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @GitGud, i think question is much more specific than the you answered. i see no reason for this question to be closed.

Comment: @abel You're right, I completely overlooked the term special. Retracting my vote. **Edit:** But a special matrix is easy to find from my answer.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible take $z = y + A^{-1}b$ to get $z' = Az$. Edit: This only works if $b$ is indepentent of $x$.!

Comment: Sometimes we use notations $x$ and $y$ in parallel ways.  But here $y$ is a vector function, and $x$ is a scalar variable.  So they are not parallel objects.

Answer (score 4):

It is the matrix exponential:
$$
e^{Ax}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\,A^n.
$$
It is a fundamental solution of the homogeneous equation $y'=A\,y$, and is the unique one equal to the identity matrix when $x=0$. The unique solution such that $y(0)=y_0$ is $y(x)=e^{Ax}y_0$.

The method of variation of constants looks for a particular solution of the complete equation of the form $e^{Ax}C(c)$, where $C(x)=(C_1(x),\dots,C_n(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

in your specific problem, it is easy to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the coefficient matrix $\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&2}.$ the eigenvalues are $3$ and $1$ the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors are first and second columns of the matrix $V = \pmatrix{1/\sqrt 2& 1/\sqrt 2\\-1/\sqrt 2& 1/\sqrt 2}.$ we have $$A =  V \pmatrix{3&0\\0&1}V^T, \, e^{Ax} =   V \pmatrix{e^{3x}&0\\0&e^x}V^T = \frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{e^{x} + e^{3x}& e^x - e^{3x}\\ e^x - e^{3x}&e^{x} + e^{3x}}$$

a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous problem $\frac{dy}{dx} = Ay + b$ is 
$$y_p = \int_0^x e^{A(x-\xi)}e^{3\xi}\pmatrix{-1\\1}\, d\xi=\int_0^x e^{3\xi} \pmatrix{0\\e^{3(x-\xi)}}\, d\xi = e^{3x}\pmatrix{0\\x}.$$

the general solution is $$y = e^{Ax}y(0) + y_p. $$

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem. One way consists in applying the Laplace transform to the differential equation so that:
\begin{equation}
L\{y'(x)\}=A L\{y(x)\}+L\{b(x)\}
\end{equation}
By writing $L\{y(x)\}=Y(s)$ and $L\{b(x)\}=B(s)$ the equation above reduces to:
\begin{equation}
s Y(s)-y(0)= A Y(s) + B(s)
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
Y(s) (I s -A) = I y(0) + B(s)
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
Y(s)  = y(0) (s I-A)^{-1} + B(s) (s I-A)^{-1}
\end{equation}
And finally we go back in the x domain by applying the inverse Laplace transform
\begin{equation}
y(x)  = y(0) L^{-1}\{(s I-A)^{-1}\} + b(x) \star L^{-1}\{ (s I-A)^{-1}\}
\end{equation}
So that when comparing the above relation to the solution of the differential equation
\begin{equation}
y(x) = y(0) e^{A x}+\int_0^x e^{A(x-\psi)} b(\psi) d\psi
\end{equation}
we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
e^{A x} = L^{-1}\{(s I-A)^{-1}\}
\end{equation}