# Let $A$ be a single $p\times p$ Jordan block. Find general solution to $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = Ax$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a single $p\times p$ Jordan block. Find the general solution to $\,\dfrac{dx}{dt} = Ax$.

What should I approach first? Please help!

Comment: I added the "differential equations" tag.  Hope that's OK; if not, you can reverse my action, though I do think it appropriate for this question.  Regards.

Comment: My pleasure, my friend!

Answer (score 3):

If 
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0&0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots &0& 0 \\ \vdots &\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots \\ 
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &1&0 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &\lambda &1 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\lambda
\end{matrix}
\right)=\lambda I+J\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}.
$$
Then $$\mathrm{e}^{tA}=\mathrm{e}^{\lambda t I+tJ}
=\mathrm{e}^{\lambda t}\mathrm{e}^{tJ},
$$
as $I$ and $J$ commute and $\mathrm{e}^{aI}=\mathrm{e}^aI$.
Also,
$$
J=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots &0& 0 \\ \vdots &\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots \\ 
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &1&0 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &1 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &0
\end{matrix}
\right),\quad J^2=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0& 0 \\ \vdots &\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots \\ 
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0&1 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and 
$$
J^{n-1}=\left(
\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0&1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0& 0 \\ 
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots \\ 
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0&0 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and $J^n=J^{n+1}=\cdots=0$. Thus 
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tJ}=I+tJ+\frac{t^2 J}{2}+\cdots+\frac{t^{n-1}J^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=
\left(
\begin{matrix} 1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2!}& \cdots & \frac{t^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}&\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \\
0 & 1 & t & \cdots &\frac{t^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}&\frac{t^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} \\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots \\ 
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &t&\frac{t^2}{2!} \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &1 &t \\
0 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 &1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: Yiorgos:  you need to bring $J$ into the numerator in the last term on the left of your last equation.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much Yiorgos! Therefore, general solution is x(t)= e^{\lambda t}e^{tJ}x(0)

Comment: I have now made the correction.

Comment: Yiorgos:  it's $J^{n -1}$!  As I'm sure you're aware.  Cheers!

Comment: I hope it is correct now.

Comment: Looks OK to me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it (with thanks to Yiorgos S. Smyrlis):

Note first that the equation

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = Ax \tag{1}$

always has the solution

$x(t) = e^{A(t - t_0)} x(t_0) \tag{2}$

for $x(t)$ with initial condition $x(t_0)$ at $t = t_0$.  Next observe that a $p \times p$ Jordan block $A$ is a matrix of the form

$A = \lambda I + N, \tag{3}$

where $N = [n_{ij}]$ is the $p \times p$ matrix with

$n_{ij} = 1 \; \; \text{if} \; \; j = i + 1, \tag{3}$

$n_{ij} = 0 \; \; \text{otherwise}. \tag{4}$

Since $\lambda I$ and $N$ commute, that is $(\lambda I)N = N(\lambda I)$, we have that

$e^{A(t - t_0)} = e^{(\lambda I + N)(t - t_0)} = e^{\lambda I(t - t_0)}e^{N(t - t_0)}; \tag{5}$

that this holds may be seen in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568450/m-n-in-bbb-r-n-times-n-show-that-emn-emen-given-mn-nm).  Now observe that

$e^{\lambda I(t - t_0)} = e^{\lambda(t - t_0)}I \tag{6}$

and

$e^{N(t - t_0)} = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{N^n(t - t_0)^n}{n!} = \sum_0^{p - 1} \dfrac{N^n(t - t_0)^n}{n!}, \tag{7}$

since, as is easily seen (and worked out in detail by Yiorgos S. Smyrlis in his answser),

$N^p = 0. \tag{8}$

It follows that $e^{N(t - t_0)}$ is upper triangular and the entries of $e^{N(t - t_0)}$ are monomials in $t - t_0$; we thank Yiorgos for taking the trouble to write them out in full.  In any event, we have

$e^{A(t - t_0)} = e^{\lambda(t - t_0)}\sum_0^{p - 1} \dfrac{N^n(t - t_0)^n}{n!}, \tag{9}$

and from here $e^{A(t - t_0)}x(t_0)$ is easy to write down.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Great. Thank you Robert Lewis.