# When $A$ is skew-symmetric, $Q = e^{A t}$ is orthogonal, i.e. $Q^T Q = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

When $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $Q = e^{A t}$ is orthogonal or $Q^T Q = I$.

(For a linear autonomous system $\dot{x} = A x$, the fundamental matrix of the system is $\Phi(t) = e^{A t}$.)

To prove this identity, I make use of the result
$$
\left( e^{P} \right)^T = e^{P^T} \tag{1}
$$
for any matrix $P$.

Since $e^P$ can be expressed as the uniformly convergent series,
$$
e^P = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \ {P^k \over k!},
$$
it follows that
$$
\left( e^P \right)^T = \left( \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \ {P^k \over k!} \right)^T
= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \ {(P^k)^T \over k!}
 = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \ {(P^T)^k \over k!} = e^{P^T}
$$

Assume that $A$ is skew-symmetric. Then
$$
A^T = -A
$$

Define
$$
Q = e^{A t}
$$

Then we have
$$
Q^T = e^{( A t)^T} = e^{A^T t} = e^{- A t} = \left( e^{A t} \right)^{-1} = Q^{-1}
$$

Thus, it follows that
$$
Q^T Q = Q^{-1} Q = I
$$
showing that $Q$ is orthogonal.

I hope that this proof is OK!

Comment: $ e^{- A t} = \left( e^{A t} \right)^{-1} $  is the heart of it. What, precisely, are you quoting?

Comment: @Dr.S Your proof is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler proof.

Define $P(t)=\exp(A^Tt)\exp(At)$. We have that

$$\dot{P}(t)=A^TP(t)+P(t)A=\exp(A^Tt)(A+A^T)\exp(At)$$

where we have used the fact that $A$ (resp. $A^T$) commutes with $\exp(At)$ (resp. $\exp(A^Tt)$).

Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $A+A^T=0$ and we get $\dot{P}(t)=0$. Therefore, we have that $P(t)=P(0)=1$.

Comment: This is a very elegant proof - I love it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

$e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$ holds when $A$ and $B$ commmute, i.e. $AB = BA$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568450/m-n-in-bbb-r-n-times-n-show-that-emn-emen-given-mn-nm).

You correctly derived that $Q^T =  e^{-At}$, and it follows that
$$
 Q^T Q = e^{-At} e^{At} = e^{(-A+A)t} = e^{0} = I
$$
since $-A$ and $A$ commute.

Comment: Thanks - It is a great proof!