# Skew-symmetric matrices and the fact that their exponential matrix is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-exponential, skew-symmetric-matrices

I want to ask why

"If $A$ is skew-symmetric ($A^T=-A$) then $e^{At}$ is an orthogonal matrix".

Here is my solution step:

$e^{At}*(e^{At})^T
=e^{At}*e^{-At}=e^{At-At}=e^0$

I think the matrix $e^0$ should be a matrix full of $1$, instead of identity matrix.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431306/when-a-is-skew-symmetric-q-ea-t-is-orthogonal-i-e-qt-q-i ($A$ is just $Q$ in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation of $e^{O}$ is wrong. $e^{O}=I+O/1!+O^{2}/2!+\cdots=I$.

Answer (score 2):

$e^0$ is the identity matrix since any matrix to the power of $0$ is the identity matrix.

This is because for any matrix $A$ we want $A^{0}A = A$ (just as $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a^{0} \cdot a = a$) thus $A^{0} = A^{-1}A = I$.

So $e^0 = 0^0 + 0^1 + \frac{0^2}{2} + \frac{0^3}{6} + \ldots = 0^0 = I$.

Note: $0$ is just a matrix full of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If the `exp()` function is applied **element-wise** then $e^0$ is indeed $J,\,$ the all-ones matrix.

However, the convention for matrix functions is to apply them **matrix-wise,** i.e. as a power series in $A.\;$
And it is only in the matrix-wise sense that the exponential of a skew symmetric matrix is orthogonal
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
A &= -A^T \\
E &= \exp(A) \qiq E\cdot E^T = I \\
}$$
In the element-wise sense, the exponential of a skew symmetric matrix is a matrix whose off-diagonal terms are reciprocals of one another
$$
F = \exp_{\varepsilon}(A) \qiq F\odot F^T = J
$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.