# Need help with simple system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

thanks to your help I advanced in computing differential equations, but now I encountered another problem I need help with - this time it is a system of differential equations:

$$x_1'=-x_2$$ 
  $$x_2'=x_1$$

I know that the answer should contain trigonometric functions, (sine and cosine) but I have no idea how to start. I tried to divide first equation/second equation and I got something like:

$$\frac{x_1'}{x_2'}=-\frac{x2}{x1}$$

Then I rewrited `x1'` as $$\frac{dx1}{dt}$$ and did the same with x2. I got rid of dt this way and got a:
$$x_1dx_1=-x_2dx_2$$
Which lead me to result:
$$x_1=\sqrt(const-x_1^2)$$
After inserting `x1` to the $$x_2'=x_1$$ equation I got some results, but neither of them contains sine or cosine. Could you point me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The point is that you cannot treat $dt$ as a variable, as you got rid of it. It is a so-called *infinitesimal*, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal.

Comment: But note also that it's not necessary to use infinitesimals in an introductory ODEs course.  Arguments typically made using infinitesimals can easily be rephrased so as to avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach (other than just guessing) is to note that
\begin{align*}
x_1'' &= -x_2' \\
&= -x_1,
\end{align*}
so $x_1$ satisfies the ODE
\begin{equation}
x_1'' + x_1 = 0.
\end{equation}
This can be solved using standard methods for linear second order ODEs with constant coefficients.

Another approach, using linear algebra, is to work directly with the first order system
\begin{equation}
x'(t) = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{A}
x(t). \quad (\spadesuit)
\end{equation}
The eigenvalues of the coefficient matrix $A$ are $\lambda_1 = i, \lambda_2 = -i$.
Finding corresponding eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ will yield the solutions
\begin{align}
u_1(t) &= e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1, \\
u_2(t) &= e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2.
\end{align}
Every solution to ($\spadesuit$) is a linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$:
\begin{equation}
x(t) = c_1 u_1(t) + c_2 u_2(t).
\end{equation}

Comment: If eigesnvectors are 1x2 vectors then how do i get the scalar $u_1$ value?

Comment: I might not have made this clear, but in equation $(\spadesuit)$, $x(t)$ is a $2 \times 1$ column vector.  $v_1$ and $v_2$ are both $2 \times 1$ column vectors.  $u_1(t)$ is a $2 \times 1$ column vector, as is $u_2(t)$.  In the final equation, the column vector $x(t)$ is equal to a linear combination of the column vectors $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$.

Comment: Much better now, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'll pitch two solution methods at y'all, one based on linear algebra and one, surprisingly enough, somewhat akin to our OP newuser's exploratory attempt centered around the derived equation

$\dfrac{\dot x_1}{\dot x_2} = -\dfrac{x_2}{x_1}. \tag{1}$

Note that I prefer the use of the "$\dot y$" notation over the "$y'$" notation for derivatives whenever possible, as I shall continue to do throughout this little exposition. In any event, the given system

$\dot x_1 = -x_2, \tag{2}$

$\dot x_2 = x_1, \tag{3}$

does indeed give rise to (1) at least in regions where $\dot x_ 2 \ne 0 \ne x_1$; I shall return to this topic momentarily, but first let me address things from the "linear algrbra" point of view.  Setting

$\vec r(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{pmatrix}, \tag{4}$

and

$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end {bmatrix}, \tag{5}$

we see that

$J^2 = -I \tag{6}$

and that (2)-(3) may be written

$\dot{\vec r}(t) = J\vec r(t). \tag{7}$

It follows from (7) that, if the initial condition at time $t_0$ is

$\vec r(t_0) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t_0) \\ x_2(t_0) \end{pmatrix}, \tag{8}$

then the solution may be written as

$\vec r(t) = e^{J(t - t_0)}\vec r(t_0); \tag{9}$

here we have that

$e^{J(t - t_0)} = I + (t - t_0)J + \dfrac{1}{2}(t -t_0)^2J^2 + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{n!}(t - t_0)^nJ^n + \ldots$ $= \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!}(t - t_0)^n J^n, \tag{10}$

just as for scalars $a$ we have

$e^{at} = 1 + at + \dfrac{1}{2}a^2 t^2 + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{n!}a^n t^n + \ldots = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} a^n t^n. \tag{11}$

Just as if follows by term by term differentiation of (11) that

$\dfrac{d}{dt} e^{at} = a e^{at}, \tag{12}$

so we see by term-by-term differentiation of (10) that

$\dfrac{d}{dt}e^{J(t - t_0)} = Je^{J(t - t_0)}, \tag{13}$

which is sufficient to prove that (9) solves (7), since we have

$\dot{\vec r}(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt}(e^{J(t - t_0)})\vec r(t_0) = Je^{J(t - t_0)}\vec r(t_0) = J\vec r(t). \tag{14}$

We next examine the specific form of the matrix exponential (10). Since $J^2 = -I$, just as $i^2 = -1$, a term-by-term comparison of (10) and (11), taking $a = i$, reveals that just as the terms of (11) contaning $i$ group to $i\sin(t -t_0)$, so the terms of (10) containing $J$ group to $(\sin(t -t_0))J$; and just as the terms of (11) which *don't* contain $i$ group to $\cos(t -t_0)$, so the terms of (10) which *don't* contain $J$ group to $(\cos(t - t_0))J$, so we may conclude that just as

$e^{i(t - t_0)} = \cos(t - t_0) + i\sin(t - t_0), \tag{15}$

we also must have

$e^{J(t - t_0)} = (\cos(t - t_0))I + (\sin (t - t_0)) J; \tag{16}$

a more complete exposition of (16) and related equations may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563145/expressing-an-oscillator-as-a-series-of-).

When the the matrix equation (16) is written out explicitly we see that

$e^{J(t - t_0)} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(t - t_0) & -\sin (t - t_0) \\ \sin (t - t_0) & \cos(t - t_0) \end{bmatrix}, \tag{17}$

and it thus follows from (4), (8)-(9) and (17) that

$x_1(t) = x_1(t_0) \cos(t - t_0) - x_2(t_0) \sin(t -t_0), \tag{18}$

$x_2(t) = x_1(t_0) \sin(t - t_0) + x_2(t_0) \cos(t -t_0). \tag{19}$

It should perhaps be observed, in the light of the above comments by newuser and Sam, that in general the formulas (18), (19) will together contain both $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms. However, with

$r = \sqrt{x_1^2(t_0) + x_2^2(t_0)} \tag{20}$

we may also write

$x_1(t) = r(\dfrac{x_1(t_0)}{r} \cos (t - t_0) -\dfrac{x_2(t_0)}{r} \sin(t - t_0)) \tag{21}$

$x_2(t) = r(\dfrac{x_1(t_0)}{r} \sin(t - t_0) + \dfrac{x_2(t_0)}{r} \cos(t - t_0)); \tag{22}$

furthermore, since

$(\dfrac{x_1(t_0)}{r})^2 + (\dfrac{x_2(t_0)}{r})^2 = 1 \tag{23}$

there exists a constant $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$ with

$\cos \phi = \dfrac{x_1(t_0)}{r}, \; \sin \phi = \dfrac{x_2(t_0)}{r}; \tag{24}$

then (21), (22) may be written

$x_1(t) = r \cos((t - t_0) + \phi) \tag{25}$

$x_2(t) = r \sin ((t - t_0) + \phi). \tag{26}$

We thus see that, with appropriate choice of the phase angle $\phi$, both $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ may be written as pure $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions with no admixture of the two. We also note that the matrix $e^{J(t - t_0)}$ appearing in (9) is orthogonal, that is

$(e^{J(t - t_0)})^T = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(t - t_0) & -\sin (t - t_0) \\ \sin (t - t_0) & \cos(t - t_0) \end{bmatrix}^T$ $= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(t -t_0) & \sin (t - t_0) \\-\sin (t - t_0) & \cos(t - t_0) \end{bmatrix} = e^{-J(t - t_0)} = (e^{J(t - t_0)})^{-1}, \tag{27}$

as may readily be verified by direct evaluation of the matrix product $(e^{J(t - t_0)})^T(e^{J(t -t_0)}) = I$. This in turn implies, as is well-known, that the magnitude of $\vec r(t)$ is constant, as may also be easily seen by computing $\Vert \vec r(t) \Vert^2 = x_1^2(t) + x_2^2(t)$; the calculations are simple, if a tad long-winded. Thus the motion of $\vec r(t)$ is circular.

Having solved (2)-(3) with the aid of matrix exponentials, what I have termed the "linear algebra" approach, I now turn to the second method of analyzing this system which I mentioned in the beginning of this post. This second treatment is in many ways similar in spirit to the attempt our OP newuser presented in his question.

First of all I think worthwhile to point out that one can get "rid of $dt$" through perfectly classical means that in no way refer to infinitesimals. Turning once again to equation (1) and the conditions $\dot x_2 \ne 0 \ne x_1$, we note that as long as $\dot x_2 \ne 0$, we may infer from the [*inverse function theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) that we may express $t$ as a function $t(x_2)$ of $x_2$ and that furthermore

$\dfrac{1}{\dot x_2(t)} = \dfrac{dt(x_2)}{dx_2}. \tag{28}$

We conclude from (28) *via* the chain rule that, writing $x_1(t) = x_1(t(x_2))$,

$\dfrac{dx_1(t(x_2))}{dx_2} = \dot x_1(t) \dfrac{dt(x_2)}{dx_2} = \dfrac{\dot x_1(t)}{\dot x_2(t)} = -\dfrac{x_2}{x_1}, \tag{29}$

which of course leads directly to

$x_1 \dfrac{dx_1}{dx_2} = - x_2, \tag{30}$

a form of (2)-(3) in which $t$ does not directly appear; we have rid ourselves of $t$ without introducing the concept of infinitesimals.

Having said these things, we further observe that (2), (3) imply

$x_1 \dot x_1 = -x_1 x_2 \tag{31}$

$x_2 \dot x_2 = x_1 x_2; \tag{32}$

adding these equations we see, after some minor algebraic mechanics, that

$\dfrac{d(x_1^2 + x_2^2)}{dt} = 2(x_1 \dot x_1 + x_2 \dot x_2) = 0, \tag{33}$

implying that $x_1^2 + x_2^2$ is conserved along the trajectories of (2), (3); hence, such integral curves, if non-trivial, must be contained in the circles $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = C^2 > 0$ a constant. Then

$\dfrac{x_1^2(t)}{C_2} + \dfrac{x_2^2(t)}{C^2} =1, \tag{34}$

from which we may conclude that

$x_1(t) = C \cos \theta(t), \tag{35}$

$x_2(t) = C\sin \theta(t) \tag{36}$

for some function $\theta(t)$ of $t$.  The implicit function theorem may now be invoked to demonstrate that $\theta(t)$ is differentiable:  setting $g(t, \theta) = x_1(t) - C\cos \theta$, we see that $\partial g / \partial \theta = C\sin \theta \ne 0$ provided $\theta \ne n\pi$, $n \in \Bbb Z$; thus the equation $0 = g(t, \theta) = x_1(t) - C\cos \theta$ defines a differentiable *function* $\theta(t)$ with $0 = g(t, \theta(t)) = x_1(t) - \cos \theta(t)$; in the vicinity of $n\pi$, we may use (36) to establish the differentiability of $\theta(t)$ is a similar fashion.  Once we rest assured that $\theta(t)$ is differentiable, we may write

$C \dot \theta(t) \cos \theta(t) = \dot x_2(t) = x_1(t) = C \cos \theta(t), \tag{37}$

which implies

$\dot \theta (t) = 1, \tag{38}$

immediately yielding the solution

$\theta(t) - \theta(t_0) = t - t_0 \tag{39}$

or

$\theta(t) = t - t_0 + \theta(t_0), \tag{40}$

so that

$x_1(t) = C\cos((t - t_0) + \theta(t_0)), \tag{41}$

$x_2(t) = C\sin((t - t_0) + \theta(t_0)); \tag{42}$

we see that (41), (42) agree with (25), (26) *via* a renaming of constants $C = r$, $\theta(t_0) = \phi$.  For more information on similar technique applied in a slightly different context, see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485115/finding-a-non-constant-solution-to-x2x2-9).

One equation, two solutions;  would that things were always this easy!  I'm more used to *two* equations with *no* solutions!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

I got this,

y' = -x and x' = y

y = x' so y' = x''

x'' = -x

x = cos(t) ; is one solution, x=Acos(t+k) represents solution set

but ACos(t+k) = A(e<sup>i(t+k)</sup> + e<sup>-i(t+k)</sup>)/2

which = 0.5*Ae<sup>k</sup>e<sup>it</sup>+0.5*Ae<sup>-k</sup>e<sup>-it</sup>

which is the same form as littleO's solution

Comment: could you explain to me how did you get from `x''=-x` to `x=-cos(t)+c` ?

Comment: sorry, x(t) = cos(t)  it is Simple Harmonic Motion I think, but (cos(t))'' = (-sin(t) )' = -cos(t)

Comment: @Sam:  I surmise that in your final expression you might want factors of $e^{ik}$ etc. instead of factors of $e^k$ etc.

Comment: @Sam: glad to see your *eyes* with my own two *i* s!